# What browser(s) does Silverlight 3 and/or 4 run under?

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

Here is an easy question.

What browser(s) does Silverlight 3 and/or 4 run under?

I know IE is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx

```
Operating System        | IE8 | IE7 | IE6 | FF 2, 3 | Safari 3 | Safari 4
 Windows Vista          |  x  |  x  |  -  |    x    |     -    |    -
 Windows 7              |  x  |  -  |  -  |    x    |     -    |    -
 Windows Server 2008    |  x  |  x  |  -  |    x    |     -    |    -
 Windows Server 2008 R2 |  x  |  -  |  -  |    -    |     -    |    -
 Windows XP SP2, SP3    |  x  |  x  |  x  |    x    |     -    |    -
 Windows 2000 SP4+      |  -  |  -  |  x**|    -    |     -    |    -
 Windows Server 2003    |  x  |  x  |  x  |    x    |     -    |    -
  (not IA-64)
 Mac OS 10.4.8+         |  -  |  -  |  -  |    x*   |     x*   |    -
  (PowerPC)
 Mac OS 10.4.8+         |  -  |  -  |  -  |    x    |     x    |    x
  (Inetl-based)

*  Silverlight 1.0 Only
** Silverlight 2,3 Only
```

For Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris: See [Novell's Moonlight](http://mono-project.com/MoonlightSupportedPlatforms).

> ### Compatible Operating Systems and Platforms
>
> Moonlight should work on any modern 32bit and 64bit Linux distributions under Firefox 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5.
>
> We make sure that the plug-in available from this site works on the following platforms: SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11, openSUSE 11.x, Ubuntu 9.10, and Fedora 12.
>
> Older distributions will run Moonlight, but may require that you build Moonlight from source code.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight supports the IE and the NSAPI plugin models.  This means that, though it's officially supported on IE and FireFox (with Chrome in experimental, to be supported in v4) on Windows, and Safari on Mac, it technically works on other browsers that support the Netscape Plugin model, like Opera.

Moonlight supports the NSAPI on most other platform, such as Linux, which gives it pretty broad support there.

Answer (score 0):

firefox, Seamonkey and safari - see this [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight#Compatibility)
There is also experimental support for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 3 supports FireFox, IE, Safari on the Mac.  Silverlight 4 is adding official support for Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

For developers IE only. You can't debug SL with non-IE browser.
For clients - almost all major browsers.

p.s. I use chrome with SL since SL2.0